# Powerpoint animation speed

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

When I animate a simple line motion animation on Powerpoint, the object starts slow, gets faster in the middle, and slows down as it reaches it's endpoint. This is undesirable for my usage - I want it to move with constant velocity, not this silly artificial-looking motion. Is it possible to control the velocity of the object along it's animation path in Powerpoint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try experimenting with the timing settings:

[image]

Comment: @aquirdturtle, Brian's answer is correct. Reduce "Smooth start" time to make the animation start more abruptly and "Smooth end" to make it stop more abruptly. Objects in real life rarely accelerate or stop instantly; that's why the defaults are the way they are.